# missing stack command Docker

Tags: docker

If I use: `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml getstartedlab` I get the error:`docker: 'stack' is not a docker command.`
If I run docker --help there really isn't a command like this:

```
rmi       Remove one or more images
run       Run a command in a new container
save      Save one or more images to a tar archive (streamed to STDOUT by default)
search    Search the Docker Hub for images
service   Manage Docker services
start     Start one or more stopped containers
stats     Display a live stream of container(s) resource usage statistics
stop      Stop one or more running containers
swarm     Manage Docker Swarm
tag       Tag an image into a repository
```

Did they change the way to do this? I'm just following the turorial of there site  [(link to tutorial)](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part3/#run-your-new-load-balanced-app)
My docker version is:

```
Version:      1.12.6
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   78d1802
 Built:        Tue Jan 31 23:47:34 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Answer (score 2):

The docker stack command was introduced in the version 1.13.
As you can see in the prerequisites of the tutorial they said:
"Install Docker version 1.13 or higher"
All you need to do is upgrade the docker version from 1.12 to 1.13